# Unable to create backup with mysqlbackup.exe (MEB)

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, mysql-5.7

I am not able to create a backup with the mysqlbackup.exe

The command:

```
Z:\path\mysql-5.7.11-winx64\bin>mysqlbackup.exe -u dba --host=127.0.0.1 --backup-image=C:\test\backup --backup-dir=%temp%\test072 backup-to-image
```

I get the following error message:

> mysqlbackup: INFO: Encryption password "encrypt-password" not specified.
>
> mysqlbackup: ERROR: Invalid options, MEB would not be able backup encrypted tables.

The DB backup is intended not to be encrypted.
Added secure_file_priv=NULL to .ini file.